# ViewFlipper: artifacts when removing all children but the last one

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I get a number of artifacts and incorrect behavior when trying to switch views in a `ViewFlipper`. I want to add and remove views **on demand**, so, instead of using XML, I must call `ViewGroup.addView()`. At certain times I want to clean up the container by removing all children but the last. Here is a demo:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(this);
        root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        final ViewFlipper flipper = new ViewFlipper(this);

        Animation in = new TranslateAnimation(-200, 0, 0, 0);
        in.setDuration(300);
        Animation out = new TranslateAnimation(0, 200, 0, 0);
        out.setDuration(300);
        flipper.setInAnimation(in);
        flipper.setOutAnimation(out);

        // clean it up
        out.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                flipper.post(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        flipper.removeViews(0, flipper.getChildCount() - 1);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        });

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Click me");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View a = makeView();
                flipper.addView(a);
                flipper.showNext();
            }
        });

        root.addView(button);
        root.addView(flipper);
        setContentView(root);
    }

    int i = 0;

    public View makeView() {
        TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        tv.setText("TextView#" + i++);
        tv.setTextSize(30);
        return tv;
    }
}
```

Sometimes I want to remove all children but the last added, to save memory and because those children will never be used again (Maybe I can recycle them, but that's another story). I use a simple runnable scheduled via `View.post()` in the animation listener, and exactly once every three times there are artifacts.

Using `View.post(Runnable)` is **required** because if you remove children directly in the animation listener, `NullPointerException` are thrown because (at least on Honeycomb+, which uses display lists to draw hierarchies).

**Note**: I'm developing for 2.1+, so the Honeycomb animation packages doesn't suit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those "artifacts" appear because in your case you try to remove all the views except the one at the top leaving the index of the current displayed child out of order. The `ViewFlipper` will try to compensate this and from the looks of it doesn't succeed. But you could still do what you want with no visual problems like this:

```
flipper.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        if (flipper.getChildCount() < 4) // simulate a condition
            return;

        flipper.setInAnimation(null);
        flipper.setOutAnimation(null);

        while (flipper.getChildCount() > 1)
            flipper.removeViewAt(0);

        flipper.setInAnimation(in);
        flipper.setOutAnimation(out);

        assert  flipper.getChildCount() == 1;
    }
});
```

This should leave only the visible View in the `ViewFlipper`. See if the code solves the problem.

Comment: +1, but -sorry!- I made that silly mistake when writing the demo. See the updated code that shows the real problem: **removals**

Comment: I tried the same solution as yours (null animation, then restored), but it doesn't work with `removeViews(start, count)`, and unfortunately my logic is that I need to keep views until some events, which causes all views but the last one removed. In my custom flipper I have a method which uses `removeViewAt(index)` with null animations and it works flawlessly. However I just found a hack to make it work: I used `removeViewAt(0)` in a loop until the children count is 1. I edited your answer and marked it as accepted :) thanks

Comment: I'd just like you to better argument the *index of the current displayed child out of order* statement. Looking at the sources, `ViewAnimator` should do its work, and I don't understand why removing the view at 0 in a loop succeeds while batch removing from `0` to `count - 1` doesn't. To me, it's a bug

Comment: @Raffaele It may be a bug in this particular case when you're trying to remove all the view except the last one. The `removeViews` method will not update the displayed child when TextView #1 enters the screen and TextView #0 will be removed(that if condition will fail). The `removeChilViewAt` has better checks so the displayed child is properly displayed in the end.

Comment: the removing should be made after slide (AnimationListener#onAnimationEnd) to avoid flickering, with animation set to null - it works in my case